# How does one use associatedtypes and typealias to reference multiple concrete classes (say) that adopt a single protocol that references Self (say)?

Tags: swift, protocols, self, type-alias, associated-types

Let's say we have the following protocol and adopting classes:

```
protocol SubProtocol {
    func doSomething( with: Self )
}
class SubA: SubProtocol {
    func doSomething( with: SubA ){}
}
class SubB: SubProtocol {
    func doSomething( with: SubB ){}
}
```

We then create a `HeadProtocol` that we need to contain an instance of 'SubProtocol'

```
protocol HeadProtocol {
    associatedtype S
    var sub: S { get }
}

class Head: HeadProtocol {
    typealias S = SubA
    var sub: S { return S() }
}
```

`class Head` can statically reference `SubA` via `typealias`, which is great, but when another class instance accesses `var sub` what it would like ideally is to be returned a concrete instance of *either* `SubA` or `SubB` depending on some sort of private state mechanism within `class Head`, something like the following, say:

```
class Head: HeadProtocol {
    typealias S = SubA, SubB
    fileprivate var isOn: Bool = false
    var sub: S { return isOn ? SubA() : SubB() }
}
```

How might that be achieved, please?

Or if this isn't possible, advice as to the best alternative solution would be gladly taken.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Shoot, dang, I read about this in a book yesterday: Extending Swift Values to the Server, but I can't remember it enough to give a decent answer.

Comment: @Zig if you remember *do please* let me know, thank you.

Comment: The problem is; how would the caller then go about using `sub`? It doesn't know the concrete type of the instance, therefore it doesn't know the parameter type of `doSomething(with:)`, so there's no way it could call it. Does `SubProtocol` have additional protocol requirements in your actual code that you would want to access on `sub`?

Comment: Hi @Hamish. Yes. Perhaps `doSomething...` is a poor example. In the *actual* code this simplified version comes from, the stateful getter is a `fileprivate var` that simply ships one of three state objects, that each contain identicial functions for populating a single TableViewController depending on the table's state. The protocol[s] that these states adopt necessarily contain an `associatedtype`, as opposed to `Self`. I mentioned `Self` as I felt it would be quicker to explain the problem.

Comment: The `protocol` that the three states adopt itself adopted `Equatable`. What I have done for now is remove it from the `protocol` and added it to the three states instead, meaning `SubProtocol` is no longer simply a generic constraint. It is a fix *of a kind* but does involve repeating `func ==()...` three times in three identical formats. That isn't great, but at least it works for now.